# Fill cell array with consecutive numbers in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Given `myCellArray{10,3} = [];`, I would like to fill in the first column with consecutive numbers (let's say 1 through 10).  I know I could do it like this:

```
[myCellArray{1:10,1}] = deal(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
myCellArray = 
    [ 1]    []    []
    [ 2]    []    []
    [ 3]    []    []
    [ 4]    []    []
    [ 5]    []    []
    [ 6]    []    []
    [ 7]    []    []
    [ 8]    []    []
    [ 9]    []    []
    [10]    []    []
```

However, if my cell array is much larger (say 1,000 rows rather than 10), writing out the comma-separated values obviously becomes tedious:

`[myCellArray{1:10,1}] = deal(1,2,3,` ... `,1000)`

Is there a way to create this comma-separated "list" of numbers automatically?  Something like `(1:10)`?  I know I could assign the values via loops, but is there an elegant one-line solution or something close to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be one way to do it with [`num2cell`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) -

```
myCellArray(:,1) = num2cell(1:size(myCellArray,1))
```

In place of `num2cell`, you can use [`mat2cell`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) which might not look very elegant though -

```
mat2cell([1:size(myCellArray,1)]',ones(1,size(myCellArray,1)),1)
```